# How can you start gazebo with a non-0 simulated clock time?

Tags: ros, gazebo

Similar to this question: https://answers.ros.org/question/310797/start-gazebo-simulation-with-non-zero-clock-time/

When gazebo starts up it starts its clock at 0, which can cause problems with code that does math on times, i.e. subtracting 10 seconds from a timestamp that is less than 10 epoch seconds will cause an error.

Does gazebo support any mechanism to change the initial clock stamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, best practice would be to set the `use_sim_time` parameter in any ROS nodes that rely on timing in the simulation. Making sure everything is sharing the same clock solves a lot of problems people encounter, so just mentioning that in case it is relevant to you.

If you are dependent on explicit time deltas, I'd encourage value checking on the timestamp or some other error handling before trying to subtract some value from it to handle errors.

All that said, you *can* start a Gazebo simulation with a given time if you're willing to edit and use a custom `.world` file. The `sdf` spec for a `<world>`s `<state>` supports a `<sim_time>` element ([see here](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.10&elem=state))

The easiest way to, in my opinion, to generate a valid world file with `<state>` filled out would be to start your world (without any spawned robots), let gazebo run a few seconds, then save your world. You can then go and tweak the resultant world file to have the desired start time. Then, you can simply load that modified world file when starting Gazebo in the future.

I am not aware of a simpler way to do this (e.g. through the Gazebo ROS launch file), but that's not to say that a better method doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks! The `.world` file option is what I needed. My problem was doing time calculations that could refer to times before the simulation start (the math is correct) so I just need some buffer for that math to happen.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative: Gazebo Harmonic has just been released and supports to set the initial simulation time through a command line argument, see [this pull request](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/pull/1687).

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified which Gazebo you mean.

Gazebo Classic has support for this [since version 11.13](https://github.com/gazebosim/gazebo-classic/pull/3294) using command-line argument `--initial_sim_time 10.0` . Before 11.14, there was a bug that reset of simulation resets the time to zero. This was fixed in 11.14.

(New) Gazebo has support for this [since version 7.5 (Garden) and 8.0 (Harmonic)](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/pull/1801/files) using command-line argument `--initial-sim-time 10.0` (notice the difference to Classic). Reset should work correctly.

---

The best way to fight against negative timestamps is preventing them in the usual math operations. Any time you write `time1 - duration >= time2`, you should rewrite it to `time1 >= time2 + duration`. This way, unless duration is negative, you prevent going to negative timestamps. But of course, sometimes this can't be avoided. And also a lot of already released code doesn't have this close-to-zero-time hardening and will fail.

---

Maybe not a problem for the OP who only needs to set simtime to 10 seconds, but if anyone has the idea of starting the simulation with current UNIX timestamp - this is possible, but at least in Gazebo Classic, I've seen some unexpected behavior mostly regarding rendering sensors (and also the GUI field for simtime kind of overflows). But I haven't yet had time to figure out the problem with sensors exactly... If you ask what is this good for, one example could be detailed simulation of a magnetometer, which needs to load precomupted magnetic field models which depend on the current year. Also, GNSS positions need to know the epoch to be precisely referenced to ground.